# auto increment file names when uploading them in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I wrote a controller to upload files to a Directory. and I want if a file exists already in that Directory ,before moving , file name To be changed by increment one unit from last similar existent file name like this:

```
test.jpg
test(1).jpg
test(2).jpg
```

This is body of my Controller

```
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$fileExt  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$destinationFolder = public_path('upload/userfiles/');
$num   = 1;

$newName = $fileName;

while (file_exists($destinationFolder . $newName )) {
    $newName = $fileName. '(' . $num . ')';
    $num ++;
}

$file->move($destinationFolder, $newName . '.' . $fileExt);
```

But this does not work correctly and create file name like this :

```
test.jpg
test(1).jpg
test(1)(2).jpg
```

Comment: Can you show how you build `$path`. It seems that the appending part doesn't go quite well.

Comment: @adhesivee, I edit my Question.

Comment: What is the value of `$name`?

Comment: @u_mulder , it was a typo.

Comment: I wouldn't go this way, file operations are very slow. Rather I would store that number in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this:

`$newName = $fileName;` 
at first is test.jpg
then you append the `($num++)` so it becomes test(1).jpg

the next time its still test(1).jpg
and you append the `($num++)` then it becomes test(1)(2).jpg

Thats it

Comment: Yes, but What do you think what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
$fileExt  = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

$destinationFolder = public_path('upload/userfiles/');
$num   = 1;

$newName = $fileName;

$appendNum = false;
while (file_exists($destinationFolder . $newName )) {
    $appendNum = true;
    $num ++;
}
if ($appendNum) $newName = $fileName. '(' . $num . ')';
$file->move($destinationFolder, $newName . '.' . $fileExt);
```

Comment: your Code for a file name `test.jpg` that not exists already , create a `test.jpg.jpg` file name

Comment: so fix it.. its very simple

Answer (score 0):

this work for me :

```
        $current_name   = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension      = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $only_name      = explode('.', $current_name)[0];
        $new_name       = $current_name;

        $destination    = Storage::disk($link_directory)->path($folder);
        $all_files      = Storage::disk($link_directory)->listContents($folder);
        $searchword     = $only_name;
        $matches        = array_filter($all_files, function($var) use ($searchword) { 
            if(strpos($var['filename'], $searchword) !== FALSE) {  
                return $var;
            }
        });

        if( is_array($matches) ){
            $new_name = $only_name. '_' . count($matches).'.'.$extension;
        }

        $filename       = Storage::disk($link_directory)->putFileAs($folder, $file, $new_name);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple helper function that generates file name:

```
if (!function_exists('generateFilename')) {
    /**
     * Generate filename
     *
     * @param string $disk
     * @param string $path
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     * @param integer $count
     * @return string $filename
     */
    function generateFilename(string $disk, string $path, UploadedFile $file, int $count = 0)
    {
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME) . ($count == 0 ? "." . $extension :  "-{$count}." . $extension);
        $filePath = Str::of($path)->finish(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)->finish($filename)->toString();
        if (Storage::disk($disk)->exists($filePath)) {
            $count++;
            return generateFilename($disk, $path, $file, $count);
        }

        return $filename;
    }
}
```